Blazor binding not working when i run the app but works on the online editors
I'm just starting out with Blazor.
I don't understand whether I am stupid or there's some kind of problem.
I've made the code as simple as it can be and it is still not working for me.
When I type in my input it doesn't get shown.
I've tried to run it in the online editors like blazor fiddle and blazor playground and it works fine but when I run it from visual studio it just doesn't work. It doesn't work with onchange as well.
<input @bind="@InputValue" @bind:event="oninput" />

<p>  @InputValue </p>

@code {
    private string? InputValue = "";
}

Screenshot
If you could point me in the right direction I'd aprreciate it

What Blazor template options did you select when you created your project.  Interactivity type and where - Global/Per Page/Component?

I used Server interactive render mode and per page/component location

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Okay, apparentely using global location helped. Thanks a lot. Why it helped is another question altogether.

Read up about the difference.  If you set per page/component then you need to set the rendermode on the specific page.

rendermode was not set for this page. So I guess I am an idiot.
